# MVC 3 - Editor template for List<> Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, list, razor, editortemplates

I am building my first Razor app and really loving it. I am trying to get the low-down on how to create an editor template that renders out an **editable** list of items without a foreach loop. Is this possible?

Here are the basics of what I am trying to achieve:

In my view (Views/Image/Homepage.cshtml) I have:

```
@model List<MyNameSpace.Image>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Homepage Images";
}

@*????*@
@Html.EditorFor(Model => Model)
```

And in my editor template (Views/Image/EditorTemplates/Image.cshtml??) I have:

```
@model MyNameSpace.Image

<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Title)</div>
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.LongDescription)</div>
```

Comment: This "just works" for me. Have you tried it? I would use Html.EditorForModel(), though.

Comment: @Craig, hmmm I just get nothing on the page - the only way I can get it to pick the template up is to do Html.EditorFor(Model => Model[0]) but it doesn't populate the fields. Tried EditorForModel too still nothing...

Comment: A little more information.  What is MyNameSpace.Image?

Comment: @Mystere Man - ? it's a class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOL this is embarrassing but worthy of mentioning, the code above works fine, I created a test list in the controller but forgot to pass it to the view :-D