# list collection within model not posting back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am clueless for the past 24 hours to figure this out. i have a model within which a collection object is populated and rendred to the view. everything renders and posts back just fine, when i post the form back to the controller the list TestExceptionDisplay is empty/null.  Please help, this is driving me crazy and i have tried a couple of different ways and just clueless now.

Basically towards the end of the view there is foreach loop in which i am rendering the 
TestExceptionDisplay property, i do maintain an index for the form collection to pick it back up on post but to no avail its always empty. it renders just fine and every item is display correctly with the right index.

```
public class RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay
{
        public string Exception { get; set; }

}


@model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntry
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/errorCode.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/testexception.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/runLogEntry.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var runlogListErrorsUrl = '@Url.Action("ListErrorCodes", "RunLogEntry")';
    var runlogTestExceptionUrl = '@Url.Action("ListTestExceptions", "RunLogEntry")';


</script>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Enter a new Run Log Entry</legend>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="exception">@(ViewBag.ErrorMessage)</div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">Load List File (Select): </span><span class="rightContent">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file1" style="width: 500px" />
            </span>
        </div>
                           if (Model.LoadListStoredFileName != null)
                           {
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">Attached Load List: </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.ActionLink(Model.LoadListFileName, "Download", new { @file = Model.LoadListStoredFileName })
            </span>
        </div>
                           }
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">Output File (Select): </span><span class="rightContent">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file2" style="width: 500px" />
            </span>
        </div>
                           if (Model.OutputStoredFileName != null)
                           {
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">Attached Output: </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.ActionLink(Model.OutputFileName, "Download", new { @file = Model.OutputStoredFileName })
            </span>
        </div>
                           }
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">Import Files: </span>
            <button name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Upload" style="width: 100px">
                Upload</button>
            <button name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Remove" style="width: 100px">
                Remove</button>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Operator")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.DropDownList("OperatorID", String.Empty)
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Run ID")
            </span><span class="rightContent">[Generated] </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Run Start Date / Time")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RunDate)
                &nbsp;
                @Html.DropDownList("Hour", ListHelpers.HourList())
                :
                @Html.DropDownList("Minute", ListHelpers.Minute15List())
                &nbsp;
                @Html.DropDownList("AMPM", ListHelpers.AMPMList())
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("System")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.DropDownList("SystemID", String.Empty)
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Run Type")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.DropDownList("RunTypeID", String.Empty)
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Run Description")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.RunDescription, new { style = "width: 600px; height=30px" })
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Assay Performance Issues")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.DropDownList("AssayPerformanceIssues1", ListHelpers.YesNoList())
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Tests/Cycles Requested")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SPTestsRequested)
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Tests/Cycles Completed")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SPTestsCompleted)
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Run Status")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.DropDownList("RunStatusID", String.Empty)
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Assay")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedAssayIDs, new MultiSelectList(RunLog.Domain.Lists.GlobalList.AssayListItems(), "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedAssayIDs))
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Error Code")
            </span><span class="rightContent"><span id="ChildDialogLink" class="treeViewLink">Click
                here to Select Error Codes</span>
                <br />
                <span id="ErrorCodeDisplay" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">@(Model.ErrorDescription)</span>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ErrorDescription)
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Test Exceptions")
            </span><span class="rightContent"><span id="TestExceptionChildDialogLink" class="treeViewLink">
                Click here to View Test Exceptions</span>
                <br />
                <span id="TestExceptionDisplay"></span></span>
        </div>

        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Service Entry Request")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.DropDownList("ServiceRequest", ListHelpers.YesNoList())
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Problem Description")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.TextArea("ProblemDescription", new { style = "width: 600px; height: 30px" })
            </span>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input id="LogType" type="hidden" value="Run" />
            <input id="ID" type="hidden" value="0" />
            @if (Model.ExitCode == "1")
            {
                @Html.Hidden("ExitCode", Model.ExitCode)
            }
            else
            {
                <input id="ExitCode" type="hidden" value='0' />
            }
        </p>

        <div id="testExceptiontreeview" title="Dialog Title" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;
            overflow: scroll; width: 800px; height: 450px;">
            <div id="testExceptions">
            </div>
            <div id="inputTestExceptions">
                <table class="grid" style="width: 450px; margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Exception String
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Comment
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    @{var index = 0;}
                    @if (Model.TestExceptionDisplay != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var p in Model.TestExceptionDisplay)
                        {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Model.TestExceptionDisplay[index].Exception
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TestExceptionDisplay[index].Exception)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                           index++;
                        }
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>



        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MaxReplicateId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MinReplicateId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OutputFileName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OutputStoredFileName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LoadListFileName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LoadListStoredFileName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MinTestCompletionDate)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MaxTestCompletionDate)
@*  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay)*@


        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent"></span><span class="rightContent">
                <button name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Create">
                    Create</button></span>
        </div>
    }
</fieldset>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/exitCode.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/exitCode.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="treeview" title="Dialog Title" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;
    overflow: scroll; width: 800px; height: 450px;">
    <div id="errorCodes">
        @Html.RenderTree(CacheHelper.ErrorCodes(), ec => ec.Name, ec => ec.Children.ToList(), ec => (ec.ID).ToString(), null, "e")
    </div>
    <div id="inputReps" style="display: none;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll be better off letting MVC do the actual iteration and naming with indexes (as is required) for the posted elements to be bound at a later time.

To accomplish that, I recommend creating an Editor Template, and using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TestExceptionDisplay)`.

Similar to what is done here: [MVC 3 - Editor template for List<> Model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6880328/1373170)

And have your editor template just render a single item (meaning, it's model will be the `TestExceptionDisplay` type, not the whole `IEnumerable`).
MVC will handle the iteration for you, as well as number each item correctly.

Comment: I made an editor template and it does render fine but testexceptiondisplay list is still null on post to controller

Comment: @if (Model.TestExceptionDisplay != null)
                    {
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TestExceptionDisplay)
                    }

Comment: @model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay
@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Exception)

Comment: Instead of that DisplayFor(), shouldn't it be HiddenFor()? Or have you defined a custom display template for the exception as well? Ultimately, in the resulting html, the name of the input element should should be something like TestExceptionDisplay[0].Exception for the first item, [1] for the second, and so on.

Comment: I see what you are saying. i changed the editor template to the following and its posting the list in a big giant block of text in view source. Did I have to put a loop where i render the editor template? This is how the list looks like in the model entity [NotMapped] public List<RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay> TestExceptionDisplay { get; set; }

Comment: @model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay
<td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Exception)
</td>

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually loop. How are the hidden fields ultimately rendered if you view the html?

Comment: its comming in the form of text rather than with indexes like you metnioned. the property is  a list in a model. really clueless, its shouldnt do that though.